# My app have no errors in android studio, but in real test on android phone it jammed

Tags: android, android-studio, lag

I can't find my mistakes......
while studying social login(google, facebook), almost don't know what to do...
I tried my best, but couldn't find errors.
When I connect my android devices and run on them, my devices get jammed.
So I should force terminate my app.

here is my code

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.acepeter.smartcalendar">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">

        <activity android:name=".SignupActivity"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>

        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".BaseActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
            tools:replace="android:value" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

splashactivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /*
        앱이 맨처음 실행하면 띄어지는 로딩 화면
        앱에서 필요한 네트워크 연결, 데이터베이스 연결
        설정 값 적용 등의 앱에서 처음에 해야할 기능을 수행하기 위한 화면

        앱 또는 서버 점검 알림창을 띄우는 화면

        Remote Config(원격 구성)
            서버에서 앱의 대한 설정을 해줄 수 있습니다.


       설정 : 사용자가 사용하는 설정이 아닌 앱 관리자가 모든 앱의 설정을
              관리하기 위한 기능

     */

    FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig;
    LinearLayout container;

//    @Override
//    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logo);
//        startLoading();
//        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
//    }
//    private void startLoading() {
//        Handler handler = new Handler();
//        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//                finish();
//            }
//        }, 2000);
//}
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logo);
        container = findViewById(R.id.splash_layout_container);

        // 전체 화면
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        startLoading();


        remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
        FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(100)
                .build();
        remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);
        remoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults);


        remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.i("RemoteConfig", "Remote Success");
                        } else {
                            Log.i("RemoteConfig", "Remote Failed");
                        }
                        displayMessage();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void displayMessage() {
        // 서버에 저장된 설정 값을 가져오도록 함.
        String background = remoteConfig.getString(getString(R.string.theme_color));
        boolean caps = remoteConfig.getBoolean("splash_message_caps");
        String message = remoteConfig.getString("splash_message");

        container.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(background));

        if(caps) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("확인", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            builder.create().show();
        }else {
            // 다음 화면으로 넘어감

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();
        }

    }

    private void startLoading() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should move this code to either MainActivity or some other class.
Splash Screens are not meant to handle this amount of work but only show your branding, initialze singletons, etc.
The reason your app freezes is because no action is performed until the RemoteConfig is done fetching & activating.

Comment: see logcat and share error